# Unity select random point inside radius

Tags: unity-game-engine

I need to select a random point inside a radius to send an enemy in a Unity game while they wait for their turn to attack. 
How do I create a radius around my gameobject and randomly select points inside it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        Vector3 centerOfRadius = new Vector3(5, 3, 0);
        float radius = 10f;
        Vector3 target = centerOfRadius + (Vector3)(radius * UnityEngine.Random.insideUnitCircle);
```